# Python GUI: How to browse a directory and read ALL files in it?

Tags: python, loops, user-interface, file-io, plot

This'd be my first post here, and I'm having serious issues about file reading with Python GUI.

So, I'm totally lost in trying to figure a smarter way to write a code in Python 2.7 using GUI to browse a directory and read ALL files in it for further operations. In my case, the files I'm reading are images and I'm trying to save it in an array.

I'm using those numpy, scikits etc, for easing my image-processing work. I am trying to process 3 images named "pulse1.jpg" to "pulse3.jpg".

Here's my work below. My apologies if it's kinda bit messy/unclear, especially since I can't post images yet:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage import color, data, restoration

# first we specify the file directory
directory = 'I:\\My Pictures\\toby arm pics'
filename = "pulse"

# initiate file reading
isfile = os.path.isfile
join = os.path.join

# first, we get the number of files (images)
# in the directory 
number_of_files = sum(1 for item in os.listdir(directory)\
                  if isfile(join(directory, item)))

X = [] # we'll store the read images here
i = 1  # initiate iteration for file reading
string = "" # initiation

# read the images from directory 
# and save it to array X
while i <= number_of_files:
   string = directory + "\\" + filename + str(i) + ".jpg"
   temp = cv2.imread(string, -1)
   X.append(temp)
i += 1
```

Thank you so much for your help, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> import Tkinter, tkFileDialog
>>> root = Tkinter.Tk()
>>> root.withdraw()
''
>>> dirname = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Pick a directory')
>>> for filename in os.listdir(dirname):
>>>     temp = cv2.imread(filename,-1)
```

maybe?

(I snagged most of this code from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/438123-file-tkinter-dialogs/)